# Perl code Save ANSI encoding format xml file into UTF-8 encoding

Tags: perl

I need to change the encoding format of a file from ANSI to UTF-8... Please suggest me to complete this, I have done using some methods. But it didn't work. Herewith I have written the   code, which I have did.

```
use utf8;
use File::Slurp;

$File_Name="c:\\test.xml";
$file_con=read_file($File_Name);

open (OUT, ">c:\\b.xml");
binmode(OUT, ":utf8");
print OUT $file_con;
close OUT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid XML file, this would do it:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_file('text.xml');
$doc->setEncoding('UTF-8');

open(my $fh, '>:raw', 'test.utf8.xml')
   or die("Can't create test.utf8.xml: $!\n");
print($fh $doc->toString());
```

This handles both converting the encoding and adjusting the `<?xml?>` directive. The previous answers left the wrong encoding in the `<?xml?>` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just wondering why did you use `:bytes` layer and not `:encoding(UTF-8)`?

Comment: @Omid, First of all, I meant to use `:raw` (fixed). As for your quesiton, `:encoding(UTF-8)` is inappropriate because `$doc->toString` produces an encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a filter, try this:

```
perl -MEncode -pwe 's/(.*)/encode('utf8', $1)/e;'
```

For example:

```
type c:\text.xml |perl -MEncode -pwe 's/(.*)/encode('utf8', $1)/e;' >c:\b.xml
```

Or modifying your code:

```
use File::Slurp;
use Encode;

$File_Name="c:\\test.xml";
$file_con=read_file($File_Name);

open (OUT, ">c:\\b.xml");
print OUT encode('utf8', $file_con);
close OUT;
```

Comment: open my $out_fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $File_name or die "could not open $File_name: $!\n";

Comment: Being an XML file, one needs to change the encoding specified within the document too.

Comment: Also, ANSI never refers to iso-8859-1, and this effectively converts from iso-8559-1 to UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Text::Iconv`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aIconv):

```
use Text::Iconv;
$converter = Text::Iconv->new("cp1252", "utf-8");
$converted = $converter->convert($file_con);
```

(assuming you are using codepage 1252 as your default codepage).

Comment: Perl already comes with a perfectly cromulent encoding library: [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode). Oh looky, it also has an [iconv work-alike](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode/bin/piconv)!

Comment: Being an XML file, one needs to change the encoding specified within the document too.

Comment: A machine's actual "ANSI" code page can be obtained from `"cp".Win32::GetACP()` instead of assuming it's cp1252.